# AutoMapping stored procedure results

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, mapping, .net-core

I'm wondering if there is any way to map a stored procedure result into into a class.

This is what I have:

```
// DbContext Class:
public DbSet<StoredProcedureModelResult> SPMR { get; set; }

// Service Class:
var result = ctx.Set<StoredProcedureModelResult>().FromSql("getXXXX p1 = {0},1).ToList();
```

This works well, however, I'm using database migrations and every time I add one this thing creates `StoredProcedureModelResult` as a table...

I tried to ignore it `onModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Ignore<SPModels.test>();
```

but this throws an exception:

> Cannot create a DbSet for 'StoredProcedureModelResult ' because this type is not included in the model for the context

I just want use the benefit of mapping, and not to get a table creation, this is a simple model (non-entityType)

BTW

- .NET Core 1.1
- Web API
- EF Core (code-first)

Thank you

Comment: You could use Dapper, it would map the result of the SP to an object

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make the type an Entity type (by registering a DbSet in your DbContext).  Just have a method that returns `IEnumerable<StoredProcResults>` (can be in your DbContext), and in it run

```
dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<StoredProcResults>(...)
```

See [Database.SqlQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx)`<T>`(...)